# How to get the IP address of Docker container using Docker SDK for Python?

Tags: python, docker, sdk, docker-network

I am launching a container with `network_mode = bridge`, when I inspect the network container in the terminal I get the container IP address.

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_id
```

However, I can't get this IP address from the container object. 
Is there any solution without searching the container in the network object?

Comment: Did you check [the docker networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks)?

Comment: Yes, but didn't help, I need to use docker SDK for python because the interactions with the docker daemon are from the flask server.

Comment: Looking up this IP address is almost never necessary (it simply doesn't work in several common situations); why do you want it?

Comment: It is an academic project but basically, I want to implement a policy rule in the openvswitch where I restrict access to that container based on the IP address.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
import docker

client = docker.DockerClient()
container = client.containers.get(container_id_or_name)
ip_add = container.attrs['NetworkSettings']['IPAddress']
print(ip_add)
```

You may need to call [container.reload()](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.reload) first to update the attributes ([reference](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2128)).

Answer (score 3):

If the IP doesn't return from `container.attrs['NetworkSettings']['IPAddress']` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58338902/913098), try the following:

```
network_name = "my_net"
container.attrs["NetworkSettings"]["Networks"][network_name]["IPAddress"]
```

For me, this was the case when the containers were created with docker-compose, with an external network.

Answer (score 1):

```
container.attrs.get("NetworkSettings", {}).get("Networks", {}).get(network.name, {}).get("IPAddress")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.